# In Contacts on my Mac how do I select a local image for a photo?

Tags: osx-mavericks, contacts

On my mac I want to be able to select a photo on my local machine and attach it to my contact. However when I click on edit on the photo.  I'm given the following options:

- Defaults
- iCloud
- Faces
- Camera

None of which allow to select of photo that is on my file system.  However I go into my contacts on my phone, I'm able to choose a photo  on my phone quite easily.  So I just want to know how to do the same thing on my mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag a photo directly onto the 'head & shoulders' square, cursor should show a green +
You are then given the option to resize & can also drag to find the best fit, then Cancel or Done.